# summing numbers in a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a hash like this.

```
products = {199 =>['Shoes', 59.99], 211 =>['Shirts', 19.99], 245 =>['Hats', 25.99], 689 => ['Coats', 99.99], 712 => ['Beanies', 6.99]}
```

It has an item number => `[product, price]`.

I would like to sum up all the prices without using the inject method.

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Not understanding `inject` is no reason for not using it. Instead, you should just read up on it, functional programming style can often lead to more concise, readable code.

Comment: Agreed with @NiklasB. here, `inject`/`reduce` is a fantastic method that, once you understand it, will make much of your code far simpler and more elegant.

Answer (score 16):

```
products.values.map(&:last).reduce(:+) #=> 212.95
```

Comment: Array has no sum method in pure ruby

Comment: You have to `reduce(&:+)` for that.

Comment: @d11wtq You don't need the `&` there, `reduce` accepts a symbol: `reduce(:+)`.

Comment: Note that `reduce` is the same as `inject`, so this does **not** answer the question per the OP's requirements.

Comment: Foul play! Using `reduce` when `inject` is not allowed.

Comment: @steenslag: I don't think the "no inject" requirement is actually sensible, especially because the reason for that seems to be non-understanding. I agree however that an explanation should be added of how it works.

Comment: @megas: Actually it's ActiveSupport that you need to get `sum`.

Answer (score 5):

Why without using inject? Inject is exactly what you want.

```
products.inject(0) { |total, (k, v)| total + v.last }
```

Sure, you can use a more procedural solution, but why?

Comment: i don't really understand the inject method. I just started learning ruby about a month ago. I have tried reading about it, but just don't understand the method. If you clear it up for me, I would probably use it. I hear that it can be really valuable.

Comment: The first argument to the block, `total`, is constantly updated with the return value of the block.  Here, 0 is the initial value of `total`, and from there, we keep adding to it.  Each time we add to it, the new value of `total` is passed back into the block for the next value in the collection.  Eventually you've added every value to 0.  Experiment with it in IRB or Pry, using an Array to start with, just doing simple maths, like `*`, `-` and `+` and it will make sense.

Answer (score 1):

```
sum = 0
products.each { |key, value| sum += value.last }
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work in any version of Ruby using only the built-in functions:

```ruby
products.values.map(&:last).reduce(&:+) # => 212.95
```

Comment: The `&` is not needed, a simple `reduce(:+)` would also work. `reduce(0, :+)` is even nicer because it also works for empty hashes.